# Filemaker: behavior of portal rows

Tags: filemaker

I am creating a contacts database using FileMaker Pro 19.  Part of the relationship diagram is shown below:

[image: relationships]

For each `Person` record, I have zero or more `Phone` records, each corresponding to exactly one `IDDCode` record.

In the layout for editing `Person` records, I have a portal (with all default options) pointing to the `Phone` table.  In each portal row I have edit boxes for the `Phone::Label` and `Phone::PhoneNumber` fields, and a drop-down control with "Display data from" = `IDDCode::DisplayCode` and the "Values from" list set up as:

[image: value list]

Hopefully it is clear enough what I am aiming for.  What actually happens is not even close to that.  Among the many unexpected behaviors:

- Changing one drop-down sets the value in all rows
- The values shown in the drop-down do not necessarily correspond to the values in the `Phone` table
- When I open the drop-down list, the highlighted default is off by one (e.g. if `IDDCodeID` is 39, the value for `IDDCodeID` 40 is highlighted)
- Some of the edit boxes are missing, e.g. the second row in the example image should have a phone number filled in

The portal does correctly display the existing (imported) data, though.  Here is an example of what I see when I try to use the layout:

[image: dropdown]

**QUESTION:**

Obviously the way I have set this up is wrong (I am familiar with databases but brand new to Filemaker).  Rather than address the problems with my setup point by point, I am hoping to find out **what is the *right* way to do this in Filemaker?**

Comment: Valuelist first field should be IDDCode::IDDCodeID instead of DisplayCode which will be saved in Phone::IDDCodeID
To check other issues, attach the database file.

Comment: Also make sure the drop-down field in the portal is `Phone::IDDCodeID`.

Comment: @michael.hor257k ah OK I see what you mean. But IDCodeID is a meaningless integer; I do want the drop-down to _set_ Phone::IDDCodeID, but I need it to _display_ the corresponding value of IDDCode::DisplayCode. And I can’t just use DisplayCode as the primary key because it’s not unique, e.g. “+1” is the code for the US but also for Canada…

Comment: To display the selected `DisplayCode` value, you can place the `IDDCode::DisplayCode` field over the drop-down field and make it non-enterable. Or change the drop-down to a pop-up menu.

Comment: P.S. I recommend you join one of the forums dedicated to the Filemaker platform - where you can get more detailed help, including example files.